# Is there a setting where I can change my Mac background to night mode after sunset?

Tags: screensaver, multitasking, weather.app

I want to customize my Mac screen to change its' appearance after sunset. I was wondering if I was able to connect the sunset time on weather to my screen so if I have a skyline of a city, for example, to change it to night time from day. Is this possible at all?